# .NET MVC 3 Programmatically set layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

In a .NET Razor Web Application i'm trying to programmatically set the `Layout`. I can not use `_ViewStart.cshtml` and don't wont to set the `@{ Layout = "..." }` on every page. This is what I have come up with:

A base `WebViewPage` class:

```
public abstract class SitePage<T> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T>
{
    private object _layout;

    public new dynamic Layout { get { return _layout; } }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        _layout = "~/Themes/" + Settings.Theme + "/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

And in the application `web.config` I specify all view to use this base page. But the `Layout` is never used it seems. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `WebViewPage` class inherits from `WebPageBase` that has a property named `Layout` like:

```
public override string Layout { get; set; }
```

You can override the `Layout` property, or change your _layout logic to achieve your purpose. For example:

```
public abstract class SitePage<T> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T> {

    // set this modifier as protected, to make it accessible from view-pages
    protected string _layout{
        get {
            return base.Layout;
        }
        set {
            base.Layout = value;
        }
    }

    public override void InitHelpers() {
        base.InitHelpers();
        _layout = "~/Themes/" + Settings.Theme + "/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

and/or in a view-page, you can set it too:

```
@{
    _layout = "_Your_Special_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**UPDATE**: using a flag to avoid stack-over-flow in assigning _layout more that once:

```
public abstract class SitePage<T> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T> {

    public bool LayoutAssigned {
        get {
            return (ViewBag.LayoutAssigned == true);
        }
        set {
            ViewBag.LayoutAssigned = value;
        }
    }

    // set this modifier as protected, to make it accessible from view-pages
    protected string _layout{
        get {
            return base.Layout;
        }
        set {
            base.Layout = value;
        }
    }

    public override void InitHelpers() {
        base.InitHelpers();
        if(!LayoutAssigned) {
            _layout = "~/Themes/" + Settings.Theme + "/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
            LayoutAssigned = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be causing a stackoverflow. When the Layout.cshtml contains a partialview, InitHelpers is called again and sets the layout, then Layout.cshtml seems to get initialized again and sets the layout again, etc.

Comment: You're right. You can do something to solve this. One of them is using a boolean-flag to check that the `Layout` is assigned or not. Which I used in my project, is that I have 3 base-class for layouts, view-pages, and partial-views. Also you can find any other ways special for your project

Comment: I can't speak English good. So sorry if my sentences are un-understandable :D

Comment: Your English is fine :D Thank you for getting me started, setting a `bool` in the `Context.Items` works OK (or ViewBag like your exmaple). Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :D Yeah, I forgot the `Context.Items` (^_^) It works too

Comment: Found this while trying to fix the stackoverflow issue - I'll mention that the above helped but didn't quite work for me. After much experimentation I found that i had to override ExecutePageHierchy rather than InitHelpers.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to achieve the same just now by implementing a custom WebViewPage, however changing WebViewPage.Layout within my custom class didn't have any effect (as you have also discovered).

Eventually I ended up changing my _ViewStart.cshtml to have this code:

```
@{
    this.Layout = this.Request.QueryString["print"] == "1" 
        ? "~/Views/Layout/_Print.cshtml"
        : "~/Views/Layout/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

It might not be implemented how you wanted it, but it certainly does keep things dry and that is the main point.