# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Custom WebViewPage can't set Layout property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Before I start, I did find this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787646/net-mvc-3-programmatically-set-layout), but I don't think it's quite the same issue.

I've created a custom `WebViewPage<T>` and set that as the base page for my views in the web.config.  This is working fine.  I've added a method like the following to the class -

```
public void SetLayout()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["abc"]))
    {
        Layout = null;
    }
}
```

There's a bit more to it in the actual use case, but this is the basic method.  It gets called from the View, and is supposed to override the layout if a query string parameter is passed.

```
@{ SetLayout(); }
```

The issue I'm running into is that Layout doesn't get set to null.  When I step through the code in Visual Studio, I see Layout is set to `"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"` (from `_ViewStart.cshtml`).  Then the code above runs and it should get set to null.  Inspecting the Layout property - immediately after that line runs - it's still set to the full string.  In the Immediate window I can override it to null - and that works - but via the code has no effect.

I've tried adding an additional Layout override to the class, using base.Layout, etc.  The base class shows that Layout is simply a property, so I'm not sure why setting it wouldn't change it's value.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but have you tried:

`@{ Layout = SetLayout(); }`

Comment: Yes - with a method that returns a string - but then I lose the ability to work with the default value of Layout from _ViewStart.cshtml.  I'm less interested in a workaround than why .NET wouldn't let me write to a cookie cutter property.  It'd be nice if it'd at least throw an error.

Comment: From its perspective, there is no error to make you aware of.  The Layout that you are setting to null has nothing to do with the current Layout of the page.  The View code is isolated from the Model code in this fashion. By just calling SetLayout() you are setting a completely different Layout Property than the one you think you are.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean or how the model factors in to this.  I can create another property in this class right along side the Layout property, and it becomes part of the view - ie. @{ SomeProperty = 1; }.  Is it an inheritance issue that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure how to explain it.  Here is how to see it in action.  If you change your @{ SetLayout(); } code to @{ SetLayout();  Layout = ""; } SetLayout() is not changing the same thing that Layout is trying to set.